# Unable to get PWA projects using rest APIs

Tags: sharepoint, progressive-web-apps, rest

I want to get sharepoint project information using rest API's with the access token generated from a registered app.
However we are running into below error when getting the projects in postman with below URL. (Which works in browser(after login) when accessed via cookie access)

Url - [https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectData/[en-us]/Projects?format=json](https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectData/%5Ben-us%5D/Projects?format=json)

Headers - Authorization - Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Accept - application/json;odata=verbose

Response -

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "-1, System.InvalidOperationException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "User:<customercontent></customercontent> not found in Active directory or in project db."
        }
    }
}
```

Any help to get past this error would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: I've the same issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68650241/get-project-web-app-and-project-online-data-with-sharepoint-app-only-registratio).

Did you find a solution?

Comment: I've got the same also. Do you have any updates? @C.Fabiani I'm interested in your opinion too :)

Comment: It's been a while.
If I remember correctly the tokens related to an app registered on the active directory only work on SPO but not on the Project Online part.
The only way is to create a service user, request the token for that user, and use the user's token to fetch projects.
I don't know if this solve the issue, It's been years, I don't remember very well.